# android Asynctask thread.sleep?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, thread-sleep

In my app when user writes wrong character,my edittext becomes red then it becomes write.Actually ı am trying to make a red blink.This is my working code

```
 class BlinkTask extends AsyncTask<EditText, Boolean, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(EditText... params) {

        EditText et1=params[0];

        try {
            et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       try {
           et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

        return true;
    }
}
```

but when I take et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); out of try-catch block.It gives no error but unfortunately myapp has stopped.I checked loggat but saw nothing.this is false code
 class BlinkTask extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(EditText... params) {

        EditText et1=params[0];

        try {
            et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


           et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);



        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it needs try-catch although it gives no error.

also ı want to ask creating a asynctask class for this task is a good solution or nwhat else can be done.thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use [animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html) for this purpose.

Comment: You cannot touch UI thread from background thread. You should do this in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask does not run on the UI thread so it cannot touch UI components. But there is a trick to do so.

```
class BlinkTask extends AsyncTask<EditText, Integer, Boolean>
{

    private EditText et1;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(EditText... params) {

        et1 = params[0];

        try {
            publishProgress(Color.RED);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            publishProgress(Color.WHITE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        et1.setBackgroundColor(values[0]);
    }
}
```

But to be honest, changing a background color of edittext in an asynctask is a bad idea. Use should take a look at animations.

Comment: thank you Bojan.why isn't it giving no error but when my app working ı get unfortunately app has stopped and nothing in logcat

Comment: if you look at my question my first code which is in fparagraph 1.But my second code in paragraph 2 is not working.They are both asynctask.Only in my second paragraph this line   et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); is not in try-catch and code is not wprking.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you now are in a different thread of main thread and edit text is one element of UIthread then you must use your code inside UIthread.

you can search for "how to use runonUIthread in java android".

hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you.But why is this code working correctly when i get this et1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); in try-catch block.